# Should I use JSF builtin required="true" validation or manully do it in bean method

Tags: jsf

I have a question what is better using   *required="true"*    in my xhtml page or do it with a method in my managed bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JSF validation (`required=true` attribute), you can skip some lifecycle phases and get pretty UI feedback for your users. As you can implements your own validators, there is not much drawbacks over validating input in the backing bean action listener.

[This article](http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.be/p/validation-in-jsf.html) explains it in details.